# Do I need to redistribute the OpenMP library with my executable for MacOSX?

Tags: c++, macos, openmp, clang++

I've successfully compiled my MacOSX console application that uses OpenMP, using clang++ with OpenMP support. I believe that linking to the OpenMP library is done dynamically, so my guess is that I need to include an OpenMP redistributable library with the executable. Is this true and is that all that's needed? I compiled the same application in Windows, using Visual C++ 12, and I needed to include vcomp120.dll with my application.

Comment: Yub, Microsoft offers a Redistributable Package which you can just ask the user to install and that will downland/update the computers DLL for the VS libraries.

Comment: Have you tried statically linking OpenMP with clang?  You can't do it with MSVC except on the xbox so you have to include vcomp120.dll.

Comment: I tried by following `-fopenmp` with `-static` while compiling, but I get the error `ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o`. Is there a way to specify that I only want to statically link OpenMP and nothing else?